# jQuery find not working with audio source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have a Rails application that has several audio elements on a single page.  To change the source on one of them, I locate the audio element with a jQuery selector, then use .find("source") to get the child source element.  For some reason, that doesn't work.  If I have an audio element with id="change_me" and a source element contained,

```
$("#change_me").find("source")
```

returns undefined.

Here's a jsFiddle that illustrates the problem.  Using find() from the parent fails, using the selector "#change_me source" also fails, but a selector that references the id of the source element directly returns the element.  What's going on?

https://jsfiddle.net/jplato/3v73nqd7/

Comment: Is HTML same as the fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) in `change_me` as it is the `id` of the `audio` element.

```
audio = $("#change_me");
source = $("#change_me source");
```

You have used the selector as `$("change_me")` which is the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) so it will search for an element with tag name `change_me` like `<change_me></change_me>`

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/faLpwr8r/1/)

Comment: Thanks, long night and I muffed the selector.  However, it's still not working in my js.erb file, and the selector is right.

Comment: @JPlato can you reproduce the issue in the fiddle

Comment: Arun, thanks for your help.  I was using a js.erb template to modify the contents of my page upon returning from a controller update method, but for some reason, I could not get it to change the src attribute of the source element (tried using attr('src', '...') and src='...'    Finally, I gave up and just decided to replace the entire div that the audio element resides in and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Its a typo. Missing `#` in your code:

```
$("#click_me").click(function(e) {
    audio = $("change_me");
               ^==========>  #
    source = audio.find("source").first();
    console.log(source[0]);
    source = $("change_me source");
                ^=========>  #
    console.log(source[0]);
    source = $("#change_me_source");
    console.log(source[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the best way to solve this, is to declare your `source` variable outside the click event so you don't need to traverse the DOM as much. By doing that you shouldn't need a global variable also.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3v73nqd7/2/)

```
source = $('audio').children('source');
$("#click_me").click(function(e) {
    audio = $("change_me");
    console.log(source[0]);
    source = $("#change_me source");
    console.log(source[0]);
    source = $("#change_me_source");
    console.log(source[0]);
});
```